Error when deploying dash app with dash-tools and render
I've created a dash app that works well on my computer. I'm trying to deploy it to web using dash-tools.
I use dashtools GUI, go through the steps to use render to deploy the app to web, but render keeps giving me the following errors. Does anyone know how to fix it?
    Running setup.py install for docopt: finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

and
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/render/project/src/.venv/bin/python3.10 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l33hk2m0/docopt_91ee242022d24b6db837ce28e9c030c2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l33hk2m0/docopt_91ee242022d24b6db837ce28e9c030c2/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-fq9i3dba/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/render/project/src/.venv/include/site/python3.10/docopt Check the logs for full command output.

WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 24.3.1 is available.

Can you deploy the app on render directly using gunicorn

Thanks for responding. I've realized the issue is with the dependencies of the libraries in my requirements.txt file. There was a github thread that helped out a bit:
https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/4483
It looks like different people need to change different things to fix the issue. I had to play around the versions of the libraries I had in here and after quite a bit of trial and error it worked. I don't like that I had to downgrade to older versions. So I guess there is a better way I still haven't found.
